# Repeatedly multiplying digits until a single digit is obtained

Tags: python, recursion

I've written code that solves a problem from [codewars.com](http://codewars.com). My code passes all the tests on the codewars site. It's a simple enough problem to solve naïvely, but I would love to improve the structure.

The prompt for the problem is as follows:

> Write a function, `persistence`, that takes in a positive parameter `num`
>   and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of
>   times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single
>   digit.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> persistence(39) => 3  # Because 3*9 = 27, 2*7 = 14, 1*4=4
>                       # and 4 has only one digit.
> ```

So my solution follows:

```
def get_digits(num, digits=[]):
    while num > 0:
        digits.append(num % 10)
        return get_digits(num / 10, digits)
    if num == 0:
        return digits


def multiply_all(digits, multiplier=1):
    while len(digits) > 0:
        multiplier = multiplier * digits.pop(0)
        return multiply_all(digits, multiplier)
    if len(digits) == 0:
        return multiplier


def persistence(num, count=0):
    while num >= 10:
        num = multiply_all(get_digits(num))
        count += 1
        return persistence(num, count)
    if num < 10:
        return count
```

I was thinking I might consolidate these three little recursive functions into one function containing all three... but I'd really like input from more seasoned programmers, so I very much appreciate you taking the time to make any suggestions.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with Python; is `count` an optional parameter? Can whatever calls your code still use `persistence(39)`?

Comment: @BrianJ `count=0` means it's optional with a default of `0`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Python 3.x bug**

Did you know that your program outputs `1` for the number `39` if executed on Python 3?

This is because of the `/` division operator on this line:

```
return get_digits(num / 10, digits)
```

The meaning of `/` in Python 3.x was changed ([PEP 238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)). Switching to `//` would be a quick fix.

---

**Improving the solution**

> I was thinking I might consolidate these three little recursive
>   functions into one function containing all three..

What if we would get all the digits of a number by iterating over the string representation of an integer and converting every digit back to an integer - `map(int, str(num))`. In order to multiple the digits of a number we can use [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) applying the [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul) (multiplication operator) function:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul


def persistence(number, count=0):
    # recursion base case - exit once the number is less than 10
    if number < 10:
        return count

    # get new number by multiplying digits of a number
    new_number = reduce(mul, map(int, str(number)))

    return persistence(new_number, count + 1)
```

Note that *you don't actually need the while loop at all*, since you are going recursive and have a `num < 10` base case as a recursion "exit condition".

---

Note that you can also approach the "getting digits of a number" ["mathematically"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/975039/771848) instead of converting the types back and forth:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul


def get_digits(number):
    """Generates digits of a number."""
    while number:
        digit = number % 10

        yield digit

        # remove last digit from number (as integer)
        number //= 10


def persistence(number, count=0):
    if number < 10:
        return count

    # get new number by multiplying digits of a number
    new_number = reduce(mul, get_digits(number))

    return persistence(new_number, count + 1)
```

This would also be generally faster than the first version.

Comment: That's an interesting way to do it! I guess I've been avoiding taking advantage of the properties of strings when it comes to numbers. Do I have a false impression of it being taboo? Your solution is definitely very neat, though. I like that. And yes... I wrote this in Python 2.7, and wasn't thinking much about 3 at the time. I need to get in a better habit of writing cross-compatible code. And I have no idea how I missed that about the while loop. That's very true. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @CaitlinQuinteroWeaver yes, this part is a bit arguable - there is that ["mathematical" way of getting the digits of a number](http://stackoverflow.com/a/975039/771848) - updated the answer with this solution applied. Thanks.

Comment: I'd argue that the while loop is actually better in this scenario than the recursive solution. Also, converting strings to integers is a time intensive process. Definitely use the mathematical way for retrieving digits.

Comment: @pzp [repl.it disagrees](https://repl.it/GF6L/1): they are about the same.

Comment: @TemporalWolf On my computer, testing both in iPython with numbers in the range 10e6 to 10e9, the mathematical solution is at least 10 times faster.

Comment: [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) FTW

Comment: @pzp strange... [repl.it](https://repl.it/GF6L/2) shows the exact opposite: at ~167k digits `map(int, str(num))` is about 100x faster. I'm at a loss to explain the discrepancy.

Answer (score 11):

What you had was generally very good. I have just a couple of notes.

The default argument in `get_digits` probably does not do what you expect it to do. That one list will be shared across all calls to the `get_digits` function. As an example, try calling `get_digits(12)` followed by `get_digits(7)`. The output? `[2, 1, 7]`. A quick fix to this is to set the default value to `None` and then conditionally initialize the `digits` to the empty list `if digits is None`.

For efficiency reasons, you probably want to avoid creating a new list every time `get_digits` is called. I recommend that you instead make `get_digits` a generator function by using the `yield` keyword. (I also gave it an optional arbitrary base argument just for fun.)

Finally, make all of the functions iterative. It probably has better performance than the recursive solution, and is logically clearer to most people.

All in all...

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul


def get_digits(num, base=10):
    while num > 0:
        yield num % base
        num /= base


def product(it):
    return reduce(mul, it, 1)


def persistence(num):
    count = 0
    while num > 9:
        num = product(get_digits(num))
        count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 10):

- I'd suggest you stay away from recursion in Python. [Python has a maximum recursion depth](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3323001), with a default of about 1000.
  This is to prevent system problems when using recursion, and the fixes of using [`sys.setrecursionlimit`](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit) are workarounds, and don't actually fix the problem.
  Instead to remove these headaches don't use recursion.
- [Don't pass mutable datatypes as default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941), this is as if you call `get_digits` twice, then it'll output both numbers.
  Take:

  ```
  >>> get_digits(12345)
  [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
  >>> get_digits(12345)
  [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
  ```
- If you need to pop data try to use `list.pop()` over `list.pop(0)`. This is as the former only has to remove one item, but the latter has to remove the first item in the list, and move all the items down to take it's place.
  [This question talks about these performance problems relative to `deque.popleft`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32543608). However here you don't need a deque, or to reverse the array in this case.

  The following is an equivalent of `list.pop`:

  ```
  def pop(list, index=None):
      end = len(list) - 1
      if index is None:
          index = end
      result = list[index]
      for i in range(index, end):
          list[i] = list[i + 1]
      del list[end]
      return result
  ```

However there are a couple of non-major changes you can make:

- If you stay with using recursion, don't use `while` as a replacement for `if`.
- If you remove the recursion, there's no need to have your `if`s in your functions.
- rather than doing both `a % b` and `a // b` you can instead use [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#divmod).
- Values in Python can implicitly be converted to booleans. An empty array is `False` where an array with at least one item is `True`.
  This also happens with ints, `0` is `False` where all other numbers are `True`.

And so changing the code to not suffer from the above problems can result in:

```
def get_digits(num):
    digits = []
    while num:
        num, digit = divmod(num, 10)
        digits.append(digit)
    return digits


def multiply_all(digits):
    multiplier = 1
    while digits:
        multiplier *= digits.pop()
    return multiplier


def persistence(num):
    count = 0
    while num >= 10:
        num = multiply_all(get_digits(num))
        count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 5):

Without changing any of the other functions, passing `count` to the recursive function isn't the cleanest way to do recursion:

```
def persistence(number):
    if number < 10:
        return 0

    new_number = multiply_all(get_digits(number))
    return 1 + persistence(new_number)
```

or, shorter:

```
def persistence(number):
    return 0 if number < 10 else 1 + persistence(multiply_all(get_digits(number)))
```

Comment: Passing `count` to the recursive function does make it *tail-recursive*, which (might) allow the compiler to transform it into iterative code.  I don't know whether Python implementations actually perform tail-call elimination, but it's certainly worth checking before making this change.